# Session not set in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I have set the session like this

```
$loc_details = array(
                   'maincity_id'  =>$maincity_id,
                   'mainzoneid'     => $mainzoneid,
                   'mainproductid'     => $productid,
               );
        $this->session->set_userdata($loc_details);
```

Here i have retrieved the values like this

```
$maincity_id=$this->session->userdata('maincity_id');

    //$mainzone_id=$this->session->userdata('mainzone_id');
        $mainproduct_id=$this->session->userdata('mainproductid');
```

but if i see the output the session is not set can any one help with this

Answer (score 1):

You need to do like this..........

```
$loc_details = array(
               'maincity_id'  =>$maincity_id,
               'mainzoneid'     => $mainzoneid,
               'mainproductid'     => $productid,
           );

 $this->session->set_userdata('loc_details',$loc_details);

 $loc_details = $this->session->userdata("loc_details");

 $maincity_id = $loc_details['maincity_id'];

 $mainproduct_id = $loc_details['mainproductid'];
```

Comment: i have tried but i am getting the o/p like this Array ( [maincity_id] => [mainzoneid] => [mainproductid] => plansfr.html )

Comment: yes o/p not getting anything but for mainproductid i am getting like this plansfr.html

Comment: after you assigned details to the array can you print them and post the output here. I mean before you assign to the session